# setState is not updating the values immediately on UI

Tags: javascript, reactjs, use-state, setstate

Helle everyone ,

I was working on react framework and was using a setState to set a value and display it on UI. But it is not immediately updating its value.
whenever I call the `computeTotalQty` function to set the value, it sets the value but the change is not reflected in containerList function which updates the value on UI. It displays the value a step later. Same is the case with containerSetList. Whenever the user clicks the removeItem button, it doesn’t immediately remove the item from the screen, though it is removed from the `containerSetList`.

Code for it is:

```
const [containerSetList, setContainerSetList]=useState<containerSet[]>([])
  const [totalQty,setTotalQty]=useState(0);

  let tempQty=0;

const computeTotalQty= ()=>{
    containerSetList.map((item:any)=>{
      tempQty=tempQty+item.quantity.value;
    })
    setTotalQty(tempQty);
  }

const ContainerList=()=>{
    return(
      <div >
         <Text alignment="center">
           Total Containers: {containerSetList.length} {" "}
           Total { unitType == "unit" ? "units" : "Weight"} : {totalQty} {unitType == "unit"?"":"gms"}
         </Text>
        <Divider/>
        <Table headerRows={1} spacing="small" showDividers={true}>
          <TableRow>
            <TableCell>Container ID</TableCell>
            <TableCell>Quantity</TableCell>
            <TableCell></TableCell>
          </TableRow>
          {containerSetList.map((item:any)=>(
            <TableRow >
              <TableCell>{item.inventoryItem.id}</TableCell>
              <TableCell>{item.quantity.value}</TableCell>
              <TableCell>
                <Button type="secondary" onClick={(e:any)=>removeItem(item)} size="small">
                  <Icon tokens={CloseMedium} />
                </Button>
              </TableCell>
            </TableRow>
          ))}
        </Table>
        <Divider spacingAfter="medium"/>
      </div>
    )
  }
const removeItem=(props:any)=>{
    let indexToRemove= containerSetList.indexOf(props);
    containerSetList.splice(indexToRemove, 1);
    computeTotalQty();
  }

return (
    <div>
      {ContainerList()}
    </div>
  );
```

Can anyone please tell me how can I solve it?

Comment: Can you upload code to stackblitz/jsfidle and so on?

Comment: Hey, can you move the declaration `let  tempQty = 0;` into the computeTotalQty method and try again.